# Purpose of Bean annotations for non-Job methods in trivial Spring Batch example

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am getting familiarized with the entire Spring stack.

I am referring here to a trivial Spring Batch example posted on spring.io: https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/

Every method in the Job Configuration class `BatchConfiguration` is annotated using `@Bean`. Except for the job method `importUserJob` is there any point in annotating singleton-type Bean helper methods invoked by the singleton-type Bean method that creates a job?

To my mind by removing `@Bean` annotations from all methods except `importUserJob` all this code is going to be invoked only once per Spring instance and only from within the `importUserJob` method.

All Spring Batch examples are shown with the `@Bean` annotation around the non-job methods so there must be something to it that eludes me.

*Pruned excerpt below:*

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {
    @Autowired public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    @Autowired public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
    @Autowired public DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<Person> reader() ...

    @Bean
    public PersonItemProcessor processor() ...

    @Bean
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> writer() ...

    @Bean
    public Job importUserJob(JobCompletionNotificationListener listener) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("importUserJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(listener)
                .flow(step1())
                .end()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1() ...
}
```

Thanks for reading and helping out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, you could write the batch without using `@Bean` for those function you mentioned and your assumptions are correct, as the beans are not used other places. (I have not tried it myself, but I think it will run - if Spring Batch doesn't use them for other stuff).

A `@Bean` annotated object gets its lifecycle handled by Spring so it can perform dependency injection properly. This way, you can seperate construction of objects from their usage (IoC). Especially, when you use autowiring, dependency injection becomes much easier.

You, could of course do this manually, but this will require a lot boilerplate code, and you'll be required to send your configured objects around. In your example, there may not be any benefits of creating beans for everything, but when the batch grows larger, I am sure you will miss the flexiblity of Springs bean handling. I have personally written a batch with some other framework without Springs dependency injection. First I had a compact model, but as thing grew, I really felt the pain of boilerplate code which effected the readablity of my code.

In addition Spring managed beans takes care of doing other stuff e.g. closing resources.

Of course, dependency injection is just a tool and can be an overkill for certain use cases. These articles may be of interest for you:

- https://martinfowler.com/articles/dipInTheWild.html
- https://sites.google.com/site/unclebobconsultingllc/blogs-by-robert-martin/dependency-injection-inversion

Answer (score 2):

The `@Bean` annotation makes the methods bean creation methods and the resulting object will be registered in the Spring `ApplicationContext` as a bean.

As a result it will participate in the lifecycle of said context and as well receive callbacks like the `@PostConstruct` annotated methods are going to be called or interface callbacks like `InitializingBean`.

If you omit the `@Bean` this will not happen. For the [FlatFileItemReader](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/FlatFileItemReader.html) for instance this will lead to the `afterPropertiesSet` method not being called, which would lead to a not fully initialized bean.

So no omitting the `@Bean` isn't something you should do as the `@Bean` is the equivalent of a `<bean />` in XML.

Comment: `FlatFileItemReader::afterPropertiesSet` only performs an assert so dropping `@Bean` only _might_ lead to an uninitialized bean. It appears as though `@Bean` is more of a best practice for all methods returning Spring subtypes. It appears this example mimics this XML fragment `<batch:chunk reader="myReader" processor="myProcessor" ...` -- while each of those are Spring types

Comment: No it isn't just a *best practice* those beans must be spring beans. You don't want to risk callbacks not being honored, next to that you also loose the ability to do late binding, property resolution etc. So it isn't just a best practice...